# What is the use of K1 & K2 in Mapper<K1,V1,K2,V2> in Word count?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I configured Hadoop (`hadoop-2.0.5-alpha`) in my system. I am able to run Word count Example. But I am not able to understand what is the use of `LongWritbale` (as a first argument of map method)  and If I want to do other things rather than word count (i.e. not reading a file) then what can I pass here.

(scenario is : I want to `count` how many files persist in one HDFS directory)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would suggest you to go through some good posts, books etc on MapReduce. Or at least try googling about it. Your question shows that you have not done any research and simply posted the question here. Have you??

Since, you are new and this is the first time, I will try answering your question. But please try to avoid this in future.

Coming back to your question, **LongWritbale**, **IntWritbale** etc are the MapReduce types like you have int, long etc in Java or any other language. Its usage in the map method is same as the usage of a datatype in any ordinary method or function, to tell the type of the variable used in that method. How would you know the type of a variable if you don't specify it? In short it represents the **type of K1**.

**If I want to do other things rather than word count (i.e. not reading a file) then what can I pass here.**

You can pass any of the MR types, or your custom types(must implement Writable and Comparable) as the type of your **KEY**. What do you mean by **not reading a file**???

Once you start a MR job on a file/directory you already have access to stuff like name of the file, path of the file etc. it's just that you should know how to use it.

**Addendum :**

Just saw your comment below. You don't have to worry about the input key/value i.e **K1, V1** if you do not want to do anything with the content of the file. Don't touch **K1** and **V1**. What you should be worried about is the output key/value i.e **K2, V2**. If you want to emit just the path and name of the file from your mapper you could do this :

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
String filePath = fileSplit.getPath().to String();
```

and emit this from your mapper. Your map() will be something like this :

```
public static class Your_Mapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

Text path = new Text();
Text name = new Text();

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
    String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
    String filePath = fileSplit.getPath().to String();
    name.set(fileName);
    path.set(filePath);
    context.write(name, path);

  }

}
```

Comment: "not reading a file" means Whenever I am running mapreduce It was reading the files content which exist in given path thats what I don't want to do .  Key (LongWritable) is coming as offset of line so control is coming in mapper as much as lines exist in file this way it is writing the same record too many times .

Comment: Don't do anything with K1 and V1. You cannot avoid the creation of these things. This is how MR works. You can skip it if you don't want to do use it.

Comment: Yes I am not doing anything with K1 and V1 but How can I skip this ?

Comment: Skip what?You can't change the way it all works. If you want to skip it just don't touch it.

Answer (score 0):

LongWritable here is the key which is obtained from inputformat used for running the job. By default, text input format is used, which returns the the position in file as key and the line as value.

You have to study the inputformats to understand what it could be if your input is not file.

Comment: because when I am trying to solve my problem , I need only path and files (inside it) but It is still reading file content . How can I avoid it ?